# MVC Pass an array of a modal to a controller using Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have the following scenario (this is just an example of the actual scenario as the actual is a lot of code).

::Entity

```
public class stuff
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string sometext {get;set;}
}
```

::Model

```
public class StuffModel
{
    public IEnumerable<entites.stuff> myStuff
}
```

::View

```
<form class="frmItem"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="Item.ID" id="Item_ID" value="something" />
    <input type="text" name="Item.stuff" id="Item_stuff" value="some text" />
</form>
<form class="frmItem"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="Item.ID" id="Item_ID" value="something" />
    <input type="text" name="Item.stuff" id="Item_stuff" value="some text" />
</form>
```

::Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionView ProcessStuff(StuffModel myModel)
{
    ...
}
```

I've tried the following to do this but I can't get it to populate the model:

```
$('.btnRecalc').click(function () {
    var stuffItems = new Array();

    $('.sItem').each(function () {
        var flag = $(this).data('haschanged');
        if (flag != 0) {
            stuff[stuff.length] = $(this).find('.frmstuffItem').serialize();
        }
    });

    if (stuffItems[0] != null)
    {
        var response = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("dosomething")'
        , type: 'POST'
        , data: { myModel: JSON.stringify({ myStuff: stuffItems}) }
        });
    };
});
```

For the "data" line of the ajax call I've tried all of the following:

```
, data: { JSON.stringify({ myStuff: stuffItems}) }

, data: { JSON.stringify({ myModel: stuffItems}) }

, data: { myModel: { myStuff: stuffItems} }

, data: { myStuff: stuffItems }

, data: { myModel: stuffItems }
```

My question is how to I post to the controller an array of the model's whose data is in the forms?

Comment: A good question... I'll edit my question to include that information.

Comment: Do you actually write to `stuffItems` anywhere? What is `stuff`? A couple of other notes on the javascript code: to check if an array has any content you can do `if (array.length)`. To add an item to an array, you can do `array.push(item)`

Comment: Sorry, yes, where it says stuff[stuff.length] it should say stuffItems[stuffItems.length].  And thanks for the js info...I'll make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: JSON.stringify({ myModel: { myStuff: stuffItems } }),
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Comment: I've noticed you were not setting data type being sent to server. Answer updated. Now it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... The office proxy got very strict and I can't respond from there. I figured a different way of doing what I needed but I'd still like to figure this out.